# How do I get a value outside the loop using PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, echo

I'm creating a small website using PHP, which is generally a site for showcasing the hospital, and I modified the code given in this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE type = 'woman' "; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    { 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $cat = $row["cat"] . ','; 
            echo $cat;                
           ////<---- echo on while (Loop)
         }
     }
```

The expected output would be as follows:

```
Output: 35,36
```

But I changed the code with the link above and it is as follows:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{ 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
    $cat = $row["cat"] . ','; 
  }
  echo $cat;              
  ///// <---- echo Out of While (Loop)
}
```

```
Output: 35
```

My expecting output would be 35, 36 outside of "while" using "echo".

What code do you recommend to output "35,36" the same code above?

Comment: Strange, as I'd expect the `$cat` variable to be clobbered upon each loop, and the output to be `36,` in your second example.  (Then again there is no order clause.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below code to achive your requirement

```
$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{ 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row["cat"];
  }
} 

echo implode(",",$data);
```

Comment: Please do not harass the OP to accept your answer in the first few seconds.  It is possible that another better answer may come along which actually tries to educate the OP.